# sqoop - trouble importing tables

Tags: mysql, hdfs, sqoop

I am new to BigData i don't know what is going on! Please note, I am learning this myself.

I imported a table called `sqooptest` from MySQL, from a db called `sqoopex8` using this command:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoopex8 \
--table sqooptest \
-m 1
```

I don't know where it goes (or imports).

There is a bunch of errors that is thrown, and honestly, i don't even know what to look for in the error. If it's the last line, it says "`16/04/23 01:46:52 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!`" Again, I am in learning phase and I am learning this all by myself, so please bear with me!

Now, I look under `/user/hduser/` and there is a folder by the name of the table (`sqooptest`). Nothing inside it though.

Next, intuitively, looking around in the Internet, i find out that MySQL saves all its dbs in `/var/lib/mysql`. Apparently, i didn't have access to it, so I had to access it from the terminal (CLI). When I did, I found all my dbs there. Now, I did this:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoopex8 \
--table sqooptest \
--target-dir /var/lib/mysql \
-m 1
```

( added `--target-dir /var/lib/mysql`)

This worked for some reason. when I do `hadoop fs -ls /var/lib/mysql` I see two files - `_SUCCESS` and `part-m-00000`. Why is that? Why did it not work in the first time.

Also, in the first attempt, even when I specify the target to HDFS `--target-dir /user/hduser`, it doesn't take it for some reason. When I give the target as a local file system, it takes it. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop Needs a empty target path to save files. the path you gave /var/lib/mysql is used as the hdfs path to save the imported files.

/user/hduser might not have worked because that directory might exist or you don't have privileges to create one. try hadoop fs -mkdir to check.

For SUCCESS and part files here is the nice post

[What are SUCCESS and part-r-00000 files in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666488/what-are-success-and-part-r-00000-files-in-hadoop)

Comment: thnx for your response. How can I delete everything sqoop (all directories and files) clear out mysql and start over? Any suggestion? I don't think anything is working out, even in an empty directory

Comment: Following options are good.
1. Run sqoop through a script and use hadoop fs -rmr to delete the folder and then sqoop-import
2. Create a hive table and use sqoop hcatalog import to overwrite the table.
 
Here are some examples and documentation

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_dataintegration/content/sqoop-hcatalog-integration.html

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_sqoop_hcatalog_integration

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334509/import-from-mysql-to-hive-using-sqoop

Answer (score 0):

By default sqoop will import the data from RDBMS to hdfs in the hdfs user directory eg: /user/hduser/[tablename]/part-m-00000 To avoid this and to store the data in our desired directory we have to mention it in the clause --target-dir. But this path should be existed except the last directory in the path. like if --target-dir is /user/hduser/mydirectory/mytabledata is the path, /user/hduser/mydirectory/ should exist in the hdfs then sqoop will create a directory[mytabledata here] under /user/hduser/mydirectory/ and will import the rdbms table data in this directory.

sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoopex8 \
--table sqooptest \
--target-dir /path/to/your/desireddir \
-m 1

Please check the documentation [here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_literal) .